# how to deploy WIM image to surface pro 2

Tags: microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro, wim, imagex, surface-2

I tried to deploy a windows image (wim) file using imageX to a surface pro 2 but the tabled is not booting up, it stays on boot menu.

any help on how can I do troubleshooting?

sorry this is the first time for me doing this on a uefi device

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall Windows on the surface from the [Download a recovery image for your Surface](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/downloadablerecoveryimage?productId=100110237)